# Servlet storing and retrieving data in a database

Tags: servlets

Maybe someona can give an example of a servlet storing and retrieving data in a database? Thank you.

Comment: May be someone should really try his best to help himself to understand how this works.

Comment: Put your mouse on top `[servlets]` tags which you placed on the question until a black info box shows up. Then, click therein the *info* link. There's one hello world example of a servlet retrieving data from the DB. Further the wiki contains some links to other examples. Once you have a real concrete question, feel free to ask it. Your question in its current form is not a real programming question. It's basically a "plz gimme code" question which is not acceptable here.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best code, but it will get you started:

```
    public class MyServletGetsDataFromDb extends HttpServlet {
      public static final JDBC_URL = "whtever:my://database/is?connection=parameters";
      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
          ResultSet results = conn.createStatement("SELECT id from table").executeQuery();
          response.setContentType("text/plain");
          while (results.next()) {
              response.getWriter().write(results.getString(1)+"\n");
          }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          response.setStatusCode(500);
          throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
          try {
            if (conn != null) conn.close();
          } catch (SQLException e) {
          response.setStatusCode(500);
          throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());
          }
        }
      } 
   }
```

Go forth and enhance it. Hope that helps.